# How request xml via PHP-cURL POST request

Tags: php, xml, post, curl

I want a PHP-cURL script to do the following request.

```
http://site5.way2sms.com/QuickContacts
POST /QuickContacts HTTP/1.1
Host: site5.way2sms.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://site5.way2sms.com/Main.action?id=0CD36BD332A5C7AE77FDBA1CBDBFFBB6.w809
Content-Length: 16   
gads=ID=e2cdae9b764355fa:T=1333862873:S=ALNI_MYvxochQ56ILMvBDr4oyyqCIDVn3w
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
folder=DashBoard
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1901
Date: Sun, 08 Apr 2012 06:07:52 GMT
Connection: close
```

I think the returned content is in XML format. How to handle them?

Comment: Where is the question my dear?

Comment: I want to do a POST request using the above details.

Comment: @Alfred... and why can't you do that?  Do you not know how to install cURL?  Do you not know any PHP?  Do you not know how to do a POST?  do you not know what a post is?  Do you not know how to send headers?  Narrow this down and explain **specifically** what your problem is.

Comment: Specifically @Alfred, what code have you tried? Add it to your post via `edit`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want generate a post request to the URL and catch the returned data using cURL you can use the following function.

```
function cURL($url, $header=NULL, $cookie=NULL, $p=NULL)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    if ($p) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
    }
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Like,

```
 $data = cURL("http://site5.way2sms.com/QuickContacts", NULL, NULL, array("post_var" => value, "another_post_var" => val2));
```